# I can't turn elements of my list into integers

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, int

I was tasked with the following 
1. Design and write a program to simulate a bank. Your program should read account numbers, PINs, 
and beginning balances from a text file. Each line of text in the input file will have all the information 
about a single bank account - account number, PIN and beginning balance. All information fields are 
separated by semi-colons. Here is some sample input:
516;5555;20000
148;2222;10000
179;9898;4500
My problem is I don't know how to turn these elements into integers I can manipulate such as were someone to withdraw money, here is what I have so far

```
def bank():
  myfile = pickAFile() 
  file = open(myfile)
  contents = file.readlines() 
  for i in range (0, len(contents)):
    items = contents[i].split(";")
  choice = requestInteger(" 1 - Withdraw, 2 - Deposit, 3 - Exit program ")
  if (choice == 1):
    PIN = requestInteger("Please enter your PIN")
    if (PIN == items[1]):
      print items[0]
    print("Invalid PIN")
```

My if statements wont work though because everything in items is a string not an int, the language is JES which uses python syntax but java libraries

Comment: What's the definition of `requestInteger`?

Comment: requestInteger prompts the user to input an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--- NEW ANSWER ---
Thanks for the feedback - you can use the same casting technique with a list comprehension.

```
items = [int(j) for j in contents[i].split(";")]
```

You could optionally surround it with a try/except block too, depending on how confident you are of the incoming data quality.

--- OLD ANSWER ---
You can cast it as an integer right after the requestInteger() call:

```
...
choice = requestInteger(...)
try:
  choice = int(choice)
except ValueError:
  # Spit some error message back
if (choice == 1):
...
```

Comment: choice isn't the problem (apologies if I made it appear that way) the problem is PIN == items[1] where items[1] is a string when I need it to be an integer

Comment: try searching for how to convert a string to an integer